# Facebook page access token for the page I am admin of

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook JS code for retrieving a list of pages of which I am assigned to as an admin. I get list of all such pages but one page is somehow not showing up. I have checked all the permissions and roles, using proper app id, also the app is showing active on that page but still somehow it is not showing up in the list and I need that page for getting page access token. Also I am using `manage_pages` permissions in Facebook JS function.

So can someone please suggest a probable reason for the page not showing up in the list. The code I am using is below (which is completely facebook code except my app ID).

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function()
{
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'xxxx6xx89xx5xxx', // app id is correct i have checked
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.12'
    });
};

(function(d, s, id)
{
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function subscribeApp(page_id, page_access_token)
{
    console.log('Subscribing page to app! ' + page_id);
    FB.api(
        '/' + page_id + '/subscribed_apps',
        'post',
        {access_token: page_access_token},
        function(response)
        {
            console.log('Successfully subscribed page', response);
        }
    );
}

// Only works after `FB.init` is called
function myFacebookLogin()
{
    FB.login(function(response)
    {
        console.log('Successfully logged in', response);

        FB.api('/me/accounts', function(response)
        {
            console.log('Successfully retrieved pages', response);

            var pages = response.data;
            var ul = document.getElementById('list');
            for (var i = 0, len = pages.length; i < len; i++) 
            for (var i=0; i < response.data.length; i++)
            {
                var page = pages[i];
                var li = document.createElement('li');
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = "#";
                a.onclick = subscribeApp.bind(this, page.id, page.access_token);
                a.innerHTML = page.name;
                li.appendChild(a);
                ul.appendChild(li);
            }
        });
    }, {scope: 'manage_pages'});
}
</script>
<button onclick="myFacebookLogin()">Login with Facebook</button>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell me if i missed something in the comments, but afaik it can only be those things:

- You have more than 25 Pages, so you need to use the limit parameter or paging. Test it with the limit parameter: `FB.api('/me/accounts', {limit: 100}, function(response) ...`
- You don´t have sufficient permissions for the Page
- It´s a bug and you should report it to Facebook

Comment: Thanks a ton. This saved me lots of headache. First point was the reason why it was not showing in the list. Thanks again.